# Write a Query which selects user name associated with a session id

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, select, linq-to-sql

This is my Query

```
select Log2002, Q116001, Q116002 from Q116 inner join log2 on Q116002=Log2001 where Q116001 in(429,430);
```

This is my result

[image]

but the desired result should be in the format- 1st Row column 1 = 429, column 2 =Rohit SIngh,Pooja,Dipesh Raj    2nd Row Column 1 = 430 , column 2 = Rohit Singh Dipesh Raj and Animesh Anand

Comment: i can not get what you are saying..

Comment: I think you're looking for the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function.

Comment: `select  Q116001,Log2002, Q116002 from Q116 inner join log2 on Q116002=Log2001 where Q116001 in(429,430) group by Q116001`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the string aggregate function group concat
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
select q116001, group_concat(log2002) from Q116 group by q116001
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Q116001, GROUP_CONCAT(Log2002)
FROM Q116
INNER JOIN log2 ON Q116002=Log2001
WHERE Q116001 IN (429,430)
GROUP BY Q116001
```